# Exception :an ole db provider was not specified in the connectionstring example would be provider-SQLOLEDB

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using this `web.config`.  I am facing the following issue after deploying the code to the server.

```
<add name="constr" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=INCHN-SQLDB01\BODSDev;Database=Tableau;User Id=Tableau;Password=olam@123; Provider=SQLNCLI11;Trusted_Connection=true;Integrated Security=false;" />
```

I am using sql server 2012.

Error msg:

> Exception :an ole db provider was not specified in the connectionstring example  would be provider-SQLOLEDB

Comment: can you attach you connectionstring seting how u r writing that without our personal data in question so that it will be easy to understand the issue

Comment: You cannot take c# executable and deploy on another computer unless the two computers have the same version of Net Libraries.  To deploy the application use publish which create a setup.exe set of folders like any commercial software.  Then install like commercial software.

Comment: Can you post the <connectionstrings> section of the web.config file for your project? It's likely incorrectly configured or not configured at all. Unfortunately, with the information you have provided it's not possible to figure out what's going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: this is my connection string:<connectionStrings>

  <add name="constr" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=xxxxxxxxx;Database=Tableau;User Id=userid;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=true;Integrated Security=false;" />   
</connectionStrings>

Answer (score 1):

The provider will need to be included in the connection string.  For SQL Server 2012 this would be `SQLNCLI11`.  You can use the connection string below.

```
<add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=YourServerName;Initial Catalog=Tableau;user id=userid;password=password;Provider=SQLNCLI11" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```